# _auth.signInWithCredential not working (stuck)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am facing an issue with Firebase phone authentication, where, when I use _auth.signInWithCredential(), it doesnt come out of the function and is stuck there...

Here is my code:

```
Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async {
          print('Verification OTP completed');
          AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
          FirebaseUser user = result.user;
          if (user != null) {
            print('User is not null!');
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'home');
          }
        },
        verificationFailed: (AuthException exception) async {
          print('There was a problem sending the otp');
          print(exception.code);
          print(exception.message);
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationID, [int forceResendingToken]) {

          createAlertDialog(context, widget.isFromGoogleAuth, verificationID);
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null);
  }
```

Next, when the user presses a button I run this:

```
onTap: (pin) async {
                    otpText = pin.trim();
                    print('$otpText');
                    AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: otpText);
                    print('${verificationID}');
                    print('${credential.providerId}');

//everything until now has been printed, nothing is null

                    AuthResult authResult = await _auth
                        .signInWithCredential(credential)
                        .then((value) {

//this value is not printed

                      print('${value.user.phoneNumber}');
                    });

//The next line of code doesnt get run, and it doesnt print value.user.phone number

                    print('I HAVE REACHED HERE');
                    FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'home');
                    } else {}
                  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that, in the test users, I had added my phone number, and instead of using the OTP code which I assigned to it there, I used some old OTP codes sent to my phone, which caused signInWithCredential to throw errors. Thanks for the help and I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onTap: (pin) async {
                    otpText = pin.trim();
                    print('$otpText');
                    AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: otpText);
                    print('${verificationID}');
                    print('${credential.providerId}');
             
                    //Made changes here
                    AuthResult authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                        .signInWithCredential(credential)
                        .then((value) {


                      print('${value.user.phoneNumber}');
                    });



                    print('I HAVE REACHED HERE');
                    FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'home');
                    } else {}
                  },
```